# numpy concatenate not appending new array to empty multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, concatenation

I bet I am doing something very simple wrong. I want to start with an empty 2D numpy array and append arrays to it (with dimensions 1 row by 4 columns).

```
open_cost_mat_train = np.matrix([])

for i in xrange(10):
    open_cost_mat = np.array([i,0,0,0])
    open_cost_mat_train = np.vstack([open_cost_mat_train,open_cost_mat])
```

my error trace is:

```
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 230, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried append, concatenate, defining the empty 2D array as `[[]]`, as `[]`, `array([])` and many others.

Comment: It is better to construct a list of arrays and apply `vstack` just once.  Repeated concatenation is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `open_cost_mat_train` is large I would encourage you to replace the for loop by a **vectorized algorithm**. I will use the following funtions to show how efficiency is improved by vectorizing loops:

```
def fvstack():
    import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(100)
    ocmt = np.matrix([]).reshape((0, 4))
    for i in xrange(10):
        x = np.random.random()
        ocm = np.array([x, x + 1, 10*x, x/10])
        ocmt = np.vstack([ocmt, ocm])
    return ocmt

def fshape():
    import numpy as np
    from numpy.matlib import empty
    np.random.seed(100)
    ocmt = empty((10, 4))
    for i in xrange(ocmt.shape[0]):
        ocmt[i, 0] = np.random.random()
    ocmt[:, 1] = ocmt[:, 0] + 1
    ocmt[:, 2] = 10*ocmt[:, 0]
    ocmt[:, 3] = ocmt[:, 0]/10
    return ocmt
```

I've assumed that the values that populate the first column of `ocmt` (shorthand for `open_cost_mat_train`) are obtained from a for loop, and the remaining columns are a function of the first column, as stated in your comments to my original answer. As real costs data are not available, in the forthcoming example the values in the first column are random numbers, and the second, third and fourth columns are the functions `x + 1`, `10*x` and `x/10`, respectively, where `x` is the corresponding value in the first column.

```
In [594]: fvstack()
Out[594]: 
matrix([[  5.43404942e-01,   1.54340494e+00,   5.43404942e+00,   5.43404942e-02],
        [  2.78369385e-01,   1.27836939e+00,   2.78369385e+00,   2.78369385e-02],
        [  4.24517591e-01,   1.42451759e+00,   4.24517591e+00,   4.24517591e-02],
        [  8.44776132e-01,   1.84477613e+00,   8.44776132e+00,   8.44776132e-02],
        [  4.71885619e-03,   1.00471886e+00,   4.71885619e-02,   4.71885619e-04],
        [  1.21569121e-01,   1.12156912e+00,   1.21569121e+00,   1.21569121e-02],
        [  6.70749085e-01,   1.67074908e+00,   6.70749085e+00,   6.70749085e-02],
        [  8.25852755e-01,   1.82585276e+00,   8.25852755e+00,   8.25852755e-02],
        [  1.36706590e-01,   1.13670659e+00,   1.36706590e+00,   1.36706590e-02],
        [  5.75093329e-01,   1.57509333e+00,   5.75093329e+00,   5.75093329e-02]])

In [595]: np.allclose(fvstack(), fshape())
Out[595]: True
```

In order for the calls to `fvstack()` and `fshape()` produce the same results, the random number generator is initialized in both functions through `np.random.seed(100)`. Notice that the equality test has been performed using [`numpy.allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) instead of `fvstack() == fshape()` to avoid the round off errors associated to floating point artihmetic.

As for efficiency, the following interactive session shows that initializing `ocmt` with its final shape is significantly faster than repeatedly stacking rows:

```
In [596]: import timeit

In [597]: timeit.timeit('fvstack()', setup="from __main__ import fvstack", number=10000)
Out[597]: 1.4884241055042366

In [598]: timeit.timeit('fshape()', setup="from __main__ import fshape", number=10000)
Out[598]: 0.8819408006311278
```

Comment: I gave the `arange(n)` as an example, but in reality the matrix will be obtaining values from a for loop which obtains data of real "costs" in a cost-sensitive classifier.

Comment: What happens if the zero columns are some function of the first column? Will this method still speed things up?

Comment: Yes, it will. I have edited again my answer to show you how vectorial code improves speed in your application.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reshape your original matrix so that the number of columns match the appended arrays:

```
open_cost_mat_train = np.matrix([]).reshape((0,4))
```

After which, it gives:

```
open_cost_mat_train

# matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 2.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 3.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 4.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 5.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 6.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 7.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 8.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
#         [ 9.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```